# What does find_one_and_update return if nothing matches the filter?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pymongo

For `pymongo` as well as other MongoDB drivers, I couldn't find any reference what happens if nothing matches the `filter`:

```
result = collection.find_one_and_update(filter, update)
```

What value does `result` take if nothing matches the `filter`?

Comment: Tried it with mongoose and got `null`

Comment: [`pymongo`: _"Returns `None` if no document matches the filter."_](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update)